# Get and display a user's profile info?

Tags: user-roles

I'd like to get specific info about all users with a certain role, then display that info on a page.

So, I'd like to:

1. Get all users with the role "Manager"
2. Get each user's avatar, first name, last name, and bio text
3. Display that info on a web page.

Note: This has *nothing* to do with user ID or the current logged in user.

How do I do this? Every option I see in the WP codex seems tied to current user or a user ID.

Comment: I suggest [WP_User_Query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

Comment: Have you tried? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a [custom template page](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/wordpress-custom-page-templates/) for this purpose and take advantage of the appropriate class provided by Wordpress itself: [WP_User_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

Eg:

```
// Create the WP_User_Query object
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query(array (
    'role' => 'Manager',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'display_name'
));

// Get the results
$managers = $wp_user_query->get_results();

// Looping managers
if (!empty($managers)) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($managers as $manager)
    {
        // get all the user's data
        $user_info = get_userdata($manager->ID);
        //printing basic infos
        echo '<li>';
        echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( $manager->ID ), 96 );
        echo $user_info->first_name;
        echo $user_info->last_name;
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo 'No managers found';
}
```